# How to deny access to all but one IP, and allow access to specific URIs for all with Apache 2.4

Tags: apache-2.4

I need to block access to site from public but allow one IP address in. And I need to give access to couple of URI-s for public. But nothing works - either all gets blocked or all is open.

Simplified extract from Apache conf:

```
<Directory /site/dir>
    Require ip 1.2.3.4
</Directory>

<Location "/open/for/public1">
    Require all granted
</Location>
<Location "/open/for/public2">
    Require all granted
</Location>
```

Now all gets blocked.

Also tried with old syntax:

```
<Location "/open/for/public1">
    Order allow,deny
    allow from all
</Location>
```

Still same.

I've tried blocking site with <Location "/"> directive (instead of <Directory> directive) but then public1 and public2 get also blocked.

I've tried with:

```
SetEnvIf Request_URI "^/open/for/public1$" NO_AUTH_NEEDED=1
<Directory /site/dir>
    Order Deny,Allow
    Deny from all
    Allow from env=NO_AUTH_NEEDED
    Allow from 1.2.3.4
</Directory>
```

Doesn't work, all gets blocked.

All suggestions welcome

Comment: *I've tried blocking site with <Location "/"> directive (instead of <Directory> directive) but then public1 and public2 get also blocked*. I just tested the first method with 3 `Location` blocks instead of `Directory` as for first one, and that works, I get blocked everywhere except the location I defined.

Comment: @Chris Thanks for having a look. Tried once more, still all gets blocked. Maybe it's the order of directives? Could you post your conf?

Answer (score 1):

What finally helped me were Apache Rewrite rules and *LogLevel alert rewrite:trace6*. In this case it appears that in addition to some .htaccess files (I didn't think had any effect) there were some internal redirects in the code. So I ended up using in the VirtualHost section something like:

```
RewriteCond %{REMOTE_ADDR} !1.2.3.4
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !^/open/for/public(.*) [NC]
RewriteRule .* - [F]
```

and in the .htaccess:

```
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule . index.php [END]
```

I added that **[END]** and seems that it is very important, as without it the Rewrite engine keeps going and for some reason, with some internal redirects (from Apache log: *...internal redirect with /index.php [INTERNAL REDIRECT]*) the URL gets mangled and *RewriteRule .* - [F]* fires every time.

Answer (score 0):

In the first example, I think you get blocked because the `Directory` directive takes over the `Location` directives:

```
<Directory /site/dir>
    Require ip 1.2.3.4
</Directory>

<Location "/open/for/public1">
    Require all granted
</Location>

<Location "/open/for/public2">
    Require all granted
</Location>
```

There are many way to achieve what you want.

- A first way that works for me is using `Location` directives only (tested with real and factice IP, public URL were real files on my system) :

  ```
    DocumentRoot /site/dir

    <Location />
        Require ip 1.2.3.4
    </Location

    <Location "/open/for/public1">
        Require all granted
    </Location>

    <Location "/open/for/public2">
        Require all granted
    </Location>
  ```

  With `Location` directives, **order does matter**. In the following example, I get blocked everywhere because the last block overrides the others:

  ```
    <Location "/open/for/public1">
        Require all granted
    </Location>

    <Location "/open/for/public2">
        Require all granted
    </Location>

    <Location />
        Require ip 1.2.3.4
    </Location
  ```
- I also tested using `Directory` directives. In this case, **order does not matter** (*the directives are applied in the order of shortest match first*)

  ```
    <Directory /site/dir>
        Require ip 1.2.3.4
    </Directory>

    <Directory "/site/dir/open/for/public1">
        Require all granted
    </Location>

   <Directory "/site/dir/open/for/public2">
       Require all granted
   </Directory >
  ```

  To choose between `Directory` or `Location` directives, see [apache recommandation](https://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.4/en/sections.html#whichwhen).
- Here is another example tested using `mod_rewrite`:

  ```
    <Directory /var/www/site/>

        # first, allow all 
        Require all granted

        # Then enable rewrite engine   
        RewriteEngine On

        # Requests that: 
        # do not start with 'test' (test is a real folder supposed open to public)
        RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !^/test

        # AND that do not start with 'another_test'
        RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !^/another_test

        # AND ...

        # AND that do not come from given IP
        RewriteCond "%{REMOTE_ADDR}"  !1.2.3.4

        # are blocked (403 Forbidden)
        RewriteRule .* - [F]
    </Directory>
  ```

Comment: Thanks for pointing me in right direction! After days(!) of banging my head against the wall I decided to try it with Rewrite rules and LogLevel alert rewrite:trace6. And it appears that in addition to some funky .htaccess files there are some internal redirects in the code. So I ended up using something like: *
RewriteCond %{REMOTE_ADDR} !1.2.3.4
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !^/open/for/public(.*) [NC]
RewriteRule .* - [F,END]